# Code examples of Pointcloud Autonomous Navigation?

Tags: gazebo, navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic, vlp-16

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently using a VLP-16 device that produces Pointcloud data type messages.  I have tried with no success to convert them to Laserscan for Autonomous Navigation (as that appears to be the popular choice) and would like to consider alternatives.

Where can I found existing robots with source code that navigate with simulation support and Pointcloud/Pointcloud2 data produced from LIDAR devices?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307010/code-examples-of-pointcloud-autonomous-navigation?/) by [bsheffield](https://answers.ros.org/users/36847/bsheffield/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer I am coming up with is that 3D navigation is not currently supported on the ROS navigation stack.

https://answers.ros.org/question/286286/3d-slam-vs-2d-navigation/?answer=286287#post-id-286287

---

Originally posted by [bsheffield](https://answers.ros.org/users/36847/bsheffield/) with karma: 16 on 2018-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-29**:\

> that navigation is not [..] supported on the ROS navigation stack

?

**Comment by [bsheffield](https://answers.ros.org/users/36847/bsheffield/) on 2018-10-29**:
Yeah I missed an important word, 3D.